# docker compose with static IP for external network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

hello i try set static IP addrees for container for external network but receive error.

```
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.5
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      my-dhcp-eth0-6d6da6:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.1.2
networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: my-dhcp-eth0-6d6da6
```

error:
ERROR: for c95a62577e09_traefik_reverse-proxy_1 user specified IP address is supported only when connecting to networks with user configured subnets ERROR: for reverse-proxy user specified IP address is supported only when connecting to networks with user configured subnets

Network already exists and work other container on it.
my-dhcp-eth0-6d6da6 is macvlan driver every container that join to it network get IP from dhcp.

What is problem ?

Comment: You're trying to configure the Docker-internal IP address of the container with an external IP address, which won't work.  Does this container need its own externally visible IP address; how do you otherwise assign IP addresses to specific processes in your setup (in containers or otherwise)?

Comment: my-dhcp-eth0-6d6da6 is macvlan driver every container that join to it network get IP from dhcp. but for this container i want set static ip address. I think problem in docker compose syntax

Comment: You should edit the question to include that detail and whatever else you've done to define the network.  Have you looked at the configuration issue suggested in the error message?

Comment: @DavidMaze added to topic about network information. I want understand what i should do for resolve proble. More then 15 container fine work with this network , receive dynamic ip, available from all local network. But how give static IP for 1 container by docker configurate i dont know.